# Bad CJK font rendering only of tabs of Firefox Snap (Ubuntu 23.04)

Tags: firefox, snap, fonts, 23.04, japanese

CJK Fonts are not looking correct but only on tabs/headerbar of the Firefox Snap as of Ubuntu 23.04. Inside the actual page, the fonts are correct as shown in the picture below:

[bad rendering of CJK fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Eh5.png)

As for relevant fonts, I have both `fonts-noto-cjk` and `fonts-noto-cjk-extra` installed, but they don't seem to be doing what they're supposed to here.

Comment: I suspect this is due to the same root cause as [bug #2017076](https://launchpad.net/bugs/2017076).

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://support.mozilla.org/ja/kb/change-fonts-and-colors-websites-use)?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, inside of the page the fonts are correct. They are only incorrect in the tabs. Changing fonts does nothing.